# Split dates into quarters based on start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to split quarters based on a given start and end date.
I have the following table:

table1

| ID | start_date | end_date | No. of Quarters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2017 | 01-01-2018 | 4 |
| 2 | 01-04-2017 | 01-10-2018 | 7 |

So the result table should be have dates split based on number of quarters and end date.
The result table should look like:

table2

| ID | Quarterly Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2017 |
| 1 | 01-04-2017 |
| 1 | 01-07-2017 |
| 1 | 01-10-2017 |
| 2 | 01-04-2017 |
| 2 | 01-07-2017 |
| 2 | 01-10-2017 |
| 2 | 01-01-2018 |
| 2 | 01-04-2018 |
| 2 | 01-07-2018 |
| 2 | 01-10-2018 |

I found a solution on stackoverflow which states

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

select
    @startDate= ET.start_date,
    @endDate= ET.end_date    
from
    table1

;With cte
As
( Select @startDate date1
Union All
Select DateAdd(Month,3,date1)   From cte where date1 < @endDate 
) select cast(cast( Year(date1)*10000 + MONTH(date1)*100 + 1 as 
varchar(255)) as date) quarterlyDates From cte
```

Since I am new to sql, I am having troubles customizing it to my problem.
Could anyone please recommend a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the recursive CTE would look like:

```
with cte as (
      select id, start_date, num_quarters
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(month, 3, start_date), num_quarters - 1
      from cte
      where num_quarters > 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79d9e2eaa3e656b258af1950d02c3ed2) is a db<>fiddle.